# Forecasting demand with out-of-stock data

Tags: forecasting, finance

Usually retailers have a service level that is below 1.0, which means that share of products is out-of-stock some of the time.

What is the best practice or possible ways of using out-of-stock data to improve forecasting, especially if it is built bottom-up?

So on top of the sales history we have availability history that has values from 0 to 1 per week/product combination including history and future weeks:

- 1 => product was available the whole week;
- 0 => product was out of stock the whole week;
- between 0 and 1 => product was available some of the time.

Comment: Can you clarify your situation? Are you asking about a case where, for a given product, each week the product is in stock `1` or out of stock `0`, and you want to use that time series to forecast demand for the product?

Comment: There is a sales history data with qty or sales per product/week and availability history data with 0-1 values per product/week. Is there a way to combine this information to improve the forecast?

Comment: I have updated the question